# Accessing bidding site auction images - Best way?

Tags: php

I'm creating a mini auction site (nothing commercial/serious, just revising PHP). Each auction will have its own image uploaded by the user that posted it.

I am trying to create this in a way that will allow it to scale up as much as possible.

**I have two ideas at the moment:**

1) Create a sub-directory for every auction and store an image inside it.

- Negative: Lots of subdirectories (performance?)

Access via: /path/auction_id/image.png

2) Create a single directory and all auction images inside it and access them via their file name. Example file name: /path/auction_images/auction_id.png

- Positive: All in one place
- Negative: Many many many files in a single directory

Is one of these ways better than the other or is there a better way of doing it altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 1 is your best option. There shouldn't be much performance difference at all, if any. If anything it might actually be quicker as if you have lots of files in 1 directory, searching though them is also a performance issue. When they are split up into sub directories, they are easy to find, easy to clean, just seems like a nicer way to do it!

You could also add a subdirectory for when the item was posted so you can clean them up very easily (cronjob or something similar) after x days (keep down disk usage). Something like:

```
uploads/{date}/{item_id}/{attachment_name (id + extension)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Different filesystems handle directories with tons of entries with varying levels of performance. However, IMHO it is a good idea to avoid having a single directory with tons of files. Both of your proposed solutions actually have the same problem in this regard - the first solution has a single directory with a lot of subdirectory entries, while the second solution has a single directory with a lot of file entries.

Instead, try something along the following lines (assuming that the auction_id is a ten-digit number, left-padded with zeros):

First-level directory: first two digits of ID
Second-level directory: next two digits
Third-level directory: next two digits
Fourth-level directory (lowest level): next two
Filename: full ID

For example, the ID 4739273912 would be as follows:
/images/47/39/27/39/4739273912.jpg

This would guarantee that no single directory contains more than 100 entries.

You'd probably want to modify this approach to handle larger ID #'s (though you'd be set with that amount for a long time, assuming sequential assignment) - or, even better, start out with randomly-generated GUIDs for your auction ID assignments.